# Problem with the factory girl cucumber step definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, factory-bot

I am using the cucumber step definitons provided by factory girl and I can not get something to work here.

First of all, here are the involved factories:

```
Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.name {|n| "User#{n}" }
  u.first_name {|n| "FirstName#{n}"}
  u.last_name {|n| "LastName#{n}"}
  u.password 'please'
  u.password_confirmation 'please'
end

Factory.define :lecture do |l|
  l.name {|n| "Lecture#{n}"}
  l.abbreviation {|n| "lec#{n}"}
  l.association :admin, factory: :user
end
```

Here is the step I am trying to execute:

```
And the following Lecture exists:                                        
      | Name                                           | Abbreviation |
      | Informatik A - Algorithmen und Datenstrukturen | ainf         |
```

I am getting this error message and have absolutely NO idea where it comes from:

```
User(#42819220) expected, got User(#43753000) (ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch)
      features/lectures/ui.feature:11:in `And the following Lecture exists:'
```

And here are my model definitions:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable

      # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name

  validates_uniqueness_of :name

  has_many :administrated_lectures, class_name: "Lecture", foreign_key: "admin_id", dependent: :nullify
end

class Lecture < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :abbreviation

  scope :ordered, order("name")

  belongs_to :admin, class_name: "User"
end
```

I am using this with spork btw.

Kind regards,

Nils

Comment: Hi, could you post your models definitions?

Comment: Hey there, sorry, have been busy the last days. I added the model definitions above. And yes, I am using spork.

Comment: Could you run Cucumber with the `--backtrace` switch and see if it gives you any more information about where the error is coming from?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1222692 <--- backtrace in here. Got the same error on another association as well and this backtrace is from the other association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, damn. Got it. I set `cache_classes` to `false` somewhere in the past because proper class reloading did not work for some reason. Just made it `true` again, and now it works. :/

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because of Spork.

The error is because at some point the `User` constant is being reloaded, but `FactoryGirl` is still referencing the old constant.  This is because you can unload constants like this:

```
Object.remove_const :User
```

See the line in this class:

- https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb#L27

You can see where this error occurs by breakpointing or just inspecting somewhere around these 2 places:

- https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/1-0-stable/lib/bundler/runtime.rb#L68
- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb#L519 (this class is the main place where you'll debug the problem)

My guess is that something is reloading `ActiveRecord` classes, but not reloading `FactoryGirl`.  One way around this might be to reset the `FactoryGirl` definitions:

```
Spork.each_run do
  # this isn't the correct api, something like this though.
  FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths = [File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'factories')]
  FactoryGirl.find_definitions
end
```

Hope that helps, Lance.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I already have this in my `each_run` block and it does not help. I have put a backtrace of the error in [here](https://gist.github.com/1222692).

Comment: Another weird thing is, that it works if I just execute the featre in question, but it does NOT work if I execute the whole test suite.

Comment: Running spork with the -d flag gave me this [backtrace](https://gist.github.com/1222692#file_spork+...+_d+backtrace).

Comment: try adding `unloadable` to the classes in question, like the user class, and even to some factory_girl classes.  It's definitely because of a constant unloading problem.  good luck.